# NodeJs Inheritance issue with node-observer

Tags: node.js, inheritance, observers

I have an issue when i'm trying to make an inheritance in NodeJS like this :

```
    var IObserver= require('node-observer');
    var Director=function(){
        Director.super_.call(this);
    }
    util.inherits(Director, IObserver);
```

And i'm getting this error :

```
util.js:634
  ctor.prototype = Object.create(superCtor.prototype, {
                          ^
TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
    at Function.create (native)
    at Object.exports.inherits (util.js:634:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (Director.js:17:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
```

I really don't know why I have this issue. 
I did it in other class and it works perfectly.

Someone else who can tell me how can I solve it ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Because require of 'node-observer' returns an instance of the class, not the constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`node-observer` returns an instance of the Observer class. So to access the Class use `IObserver.constructor`:

```
var IObserver= require('node-observer');
var Director=function(){
    Director.super_.call(this);
}
util.inherits(Director, IObserver.constructor);
```

Comment: That was the issue ! Thank you ! 
I was suspected that the constructor was not passed correctly.